# Custom HTTP Authorization Header

Tags: http, rest, header, authorization

I was wondering if it's acceptable to put custom data in an HTTP authorization header. We're designing a RESTful API and we may need a way to specify a custom method of authorization. As an example, let's call it `FIRE-TOKEN` authentication.

Would something like this be valid and allowed according to the spec: `Authorization: FIRE-TOKEN 0PN5J17HBGZHT7JJ3X82:frJIUN8DYpKDtOLCwo//yllqDzg=`

The first part of the second string (before the ':') is the API key, the second part is a hash of query string.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

The format defined in [RFC2617](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt) is `credentials = auth-scheme #auth-param`. So, in agreeing with fumanchu, I think the corrected authorization scheme would look like

```
Authorization: FIRE-TOKEN apikey="0PN5J17HBGZHT7JJ3X82", hash="frJIUN8DYpKDtOLCwo//yllqDzg="
```

Where `FIRE-TOKEN` is the scheme and the two key-value pairs are the auth parameters. Though I believe the quotes are optional (from Apendix B of p7-auth-19)...

```
auth-param = token BWS "=" BWS ( token / quoted-string )
```

I believe this fits the latest standards, is already in use (see below), and provides a key-value format for simple extension (if you need additional parameters).

Some examples of this auth-param syntax can be seen here...

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p7-auth-19#section-4.4

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_clientlogin

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/AuthSub#WorkingAuthSub

Comment: [Amazon's simple storage API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-auth-using-authorization-header.html) offers another example.

Answer (score 20):

Put it in a separate, custom header.

Overloading the standard HTTP headers is probably going to cause more confusion than it's worth, and will violate the [principle of least surprise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment). It might also lead to interoperability problems for your API client programmers who want to use off-the-shelf tool kits that can only deal with the standard form of typical HTTP headers (such as `Authorization`).

Comment: This might be harder to get right than it appears. The link that fumanchu provides (in a comment to his answer) explains why introducing a custom header adds the additional burden of now having to manually set the Cache-Control correctly.

Comment: Also, if you are making an cross-origin request via the browser, you are now in pre-flight territory just because of the custom header where you otherwise could have avoided it. For certain applications, these requests add up.

Comment: Huge no to custom authentication headers. The spec-standard `Authorization` header with your own custom scheme should be more than sufficient.  Plus you avoid pre-flight Origin requests as @wilmoore indicates.  Custom schemes do not interfere with any reasonably modern HTTP server that I know of, plus if you use your own scheme, you'll have to parse it yourself - no library should conflict (otherwise the library is written poorly).

Comment: A good reason to transmit credentials in the `Authorization` header, rather than in a custom header, is that proxies and loggers know to treat the information as being sensitive.

Answer (score 15):

No, that is not a valid production according to the "credentials" definition in [RFC 2617](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt). You give a valid auth-scheme, but auth-param values must be of the form `token "=" ( token | quoted-string )` (see section 1.2), and your example doesn't use "=" that way.

Comment: That's not correct. See page 5 of the document for an example format: Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==

Comment: That's true. But as http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p7-auth-16#section-2.3.1 says, "The "b64token" notation was introduced for compatibility with existing authentication schemes and can only be used once per challenge/credentials.  New schemes thus ought to use the "auth-param" syntax instead, because otherwise future extensions will be impossible." See also the cache discussion there regarding doing auth in custom headers.

Answer (score 9):

Old question I know, but for the curious:

Believe it or not, this issue was solved ~2 decades ago with HTTP BASIC, which passes the value as base64 encoded username:password. (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Client_side)

You could do the same, so that the example above would become:

```
Authorization: FIRE-TOKEN MFBONUoxN0hCR1pIVDdKSjNYODI6ZnJKSVVOOERZcEtEdE9MQ3dvLy95bGxxRHpnPQ==
```

Comment: I would advise against this answer, as, [per a comment on another answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802116/custom-http-authorization-header#comment9522460_7809486), the notation used here is for compatibility with existing schemes and is not recommended for new extensions.