# How to send additional data with GET,POST,PUT,DELETE?

Tags: http, rest, post, get, http-headers

For rest security I want to send an application key and a hash with every request. Actually I  would like to have it as url parameter like

```
 DELETE api.project.com/model/1?client=12345?hash=abcdef
```

Do you see any problem with this? Is there another way to send this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `Authorization` HTTP header in request. If you send it as a query parameter it can be cached in many places i.e. user's browser, http caching proxy which may lead to leak of user's credentials.

On SO: [Custom HTTP Authorization Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802116/custom-http-authorization-header)