# Should I store info to authenticate user in their session?

Tags: node.js, session, cookies

After I have authenticated a user, should I store this info in `req.session` to authenticate again and again from there on? (https://stackoverflow.com/a/8003291/1266650)

My main concern is that, it is my understanding that session are nothing but cookies (right?), so can't anyone just set their cookies in an expected manner and cheat his way into appearing like a logged in user even without going through the login procedure?

(I'm making an app in node.js)

Comment: What you're describing is a well known technique called session hijacking , this is why your session cookies should be HTTP-only and randomg UUIDs rather than let's say.. sequential numbers. If you're using something other than the native HTTP server (like connect/express) you should be covered anyway.

Comment: Ah. I knew I vaguely remember reading this stuff somewhere but couldn't remember in detail. Thanks, I'll look more into it.

Comment: Here is where you should start: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_hijacking_attack and even better https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do as the link you provided, it is correct.

As said [Benjamin Gruenbaum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1348195/benjamin-gruenbaum):
If you're using a module like `express`, it take care of possibility of `session hijacking`.

But if you want more security into your `session tracking` and understand it, you can make it by yourself. (here an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20558178/keeping-a-user-logged-in-with-nodejs/20888764#20888764) to guide you)