# Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient Authorization header without scheme.

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-8.1, uwp, winrt-httpclient

I have a winrt app and a `Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient`

I want to set its Authorization header without using a scheme. My code is as below.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new HttpCredentialsHeaderValue("Scheme", "mytoken");
```

This will result in this 
**Authorization: Scheme mytoken**

What I want is this
**Authorization: mytoken**

The problem is that the Constuctor of `HttpCredentialsHeaderValue` has to take a scheme argument and that scheme cannot be `String.empty`

Is there a way I can achieve this result?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11420667/95190 Your format isn't valid per spec. Can you change the server?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @WiredPrairie . I understand why the HttpClient works that way now. However the server is beyond my control. Do you know of a way to format the Authorization header ommiting the scheme?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAppendWithoutValidation(
    "Authorization",
     "mytoken");
```