# Purpose of auth-scheme in HTTP Authorization header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, authorization, jwt

I have a question regarding the `auth-scheme`. I stumble across JSON Web Tokens and one of the official page:

https://jwt.io/introduction/

They use

```
Authorization: Bearer <token>
```

In the past, I am familiar with the `Authorization: JWT <token>` and had assume that was correct until today, I read the official JWT webpage and they used `Bearer <token>` instead.

I was testing the Knock Rails gem: https://github.com/nsarno/knock and with this library, I was able to make a Postman request to my Rails API with random auth-scheme:

[image: example 1]

I could even get rid of the auth-scheme completely:

[image: example 2]

When I remove my JWT token from the Authorization header, however, it returns 401 Unauthorized response as expected, so I know it's...working?

[image: example 3]

So I began to think...is there a purpose to the auth-scheme ?

Is a library or web server suppose to honour/respect/enforce the correct usage of auth-scheme in the Authorization header?

I came across this Stackoverflow post in my quest for answer:

[Custom HTTP Authorization Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802116/custom-http-authorization-header)

It showed the official format is:

```
credentials = auth-scheme #auth-param
```

The example given was even more bizarre:

```
Authorization: FIRE-TOKEN apikey="0PN5J17HBGZHT7JJ3X82", hash="frJIUN8DYpKDtOLCwo//yllqDzg="
```

I don't know if this qualifies as a programming question. I can blindly follow/use a third party library.

What's the purpose of the auth-scheme ?

I'm no cryptography/computer security expert.

Maybe someone can shed some light on the issue (or maybe non-issue?) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The authorization scheme is just an indication to the server of what type of credentials are following. A client can use [basic](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617#section-2) scheme

```
Authorization: Basic <base64(username:password)>
```

Or [bearer](http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-bearer.html#authz-header) scheme

```
Authorization: Bearer <base64(JWT)>
```

Or the [Hawk](https://github.com/hueniverse/hawk) scheme

```
Authorization: Hawk id="...", ts="...", nonce="...", ext="...", mac="..."
```

Or any other scheme it can agree on with the server.

Comment: Yes, auth-scheme is to tell the server what the following token is, that's rather obvious. The more important question is whether a server should enforce it ?

Comment: @Zhang If the server only takes JWT tokens as authorization, it can be forgiving and ignore the auth scheme identifier. But if the server supports multiple auth schemes, it needs the identifier to be able to tell what is following it.

Comment: Sounds sensible :) I guess my concern is whether it poses as a security problem in the future if the server doesn't enforce the auth-scheme with received token.

Comment: I don't see a security concern. As long as the passed credentials are validated. But neither do I see any advantage in omitting the identifier.