# Custom authorization via HTTP headers in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, http, header, authorization

I have 2 internal Rails services, which need to speak to each other.
I need an advice how to make it secure enough and with minimum effort.

Currently service A sends `Authorization` HTTP header to service B, which contains secret token. Simple HTTP Token-based method, nothing special. But I also need somehow to communicate a user token, so service B will know, which user is talking to it.

My current solution is following:

1. send `Authorization Token token=blabla user_token=blabla2`
2. use [existing in Rails](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Token.html#method-i-token_and_options) methods to parse it
3. identify user by provided `user_token`
4. inspired by this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802116/custom-http-authorization-header)

Alternatives:

1. [Amazon way](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-auth-using-authorization-header.html) with something like: *Authorization: MY-APP-V1 Token=blabla Credential=user_token*, but I need custom parser for it.
2. Custom HTTP header like `X-USER-TOKEN`, but seems like [RFC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561381/custom-http-headers-naming-conventions) is not in favor of this idea.
3. Your proposal or suggestion

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm curious as to why the user token is not enough, can you elaborate on this?

But assuming you want to continue with the double-token approach, something like [JWT](https://github.com/jwt/ruby-jwt) could be used to encode the user token with the secret token. That way you will just have 1 token and can send it simply as `Authorization: Bearer xxxxxx`.

Comment: Thank you for answer.
Secret token plays role of secure authentication for service-to-service communication. Not all API endpoints need user token.
User token plays role of authorization here.